# Convert List data(contains Strings separated by delimiter) to XML(parent-child type relationship)

Tags: java, xml, data-structures, tree, nodes

We have such type of data in database column named "name".We have fetched this data in an Array List in Java.

```
Mobile.
Mobile.Network.
Mobile.Network.Signal.Strength.
Mobile.Network.Signal.Range.
Mobile.Wattage.Power
Mobile.Wattage.Specification.
```

[Here Mobile is Parent and Network & Wattage are Child,subsequently Network & Wattage are parent for Signal,Power & Wattage and so on... ]

We need to convert this into XML ,so that we can have such output.

```
<Mobile>
<Network>
<Signal>
<Strength></Strength>
<Range></Range>
</Signal>
</Network>
<Wattage>
<Power></Power>
<Specification></Specification>
</Wattage>
</Mobile>
```

Comment: You should at least include some basic thoughts or some pseudocode to highlight that you've actually be working at this at all

Answer (score 0):

XML is built on XSD with data in it.
I don't understand what data needs to be added in XML from your input.

Further, do you have an XSD or just want to build a string with above input from DB

Comment: NO we don't have XSD ,we just need to work upon these strings to convert them into described xml